# I created an app, but can not add my fan page

Tags: facebook, tabs, icons, favicon

How do I put a tab with custom icons in my fan page.

I created an app, I modified the icon, but can not add the application on my page.
also can not add the app Videobox,

but I can add a Static FBML app ....

can be a problem in my page?

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your application profile site. There on the bottom left you should have a menu link which says Add to my page. Click this and pick your page where you want to add this app. After that, go to your page administration and check pages applications. There you should have your app and option to add ot as a tab.